# How to plot time series?

Tags: python

I have this sample text file that contains time series data with ID, Date Time, count, and delta. I need to produce an hourly time series and fill in the missing hours with zero. The range of the series would be 2010/10/20 thru 2010/12/31. Here is a sample of the text file:

0620,2010/10/20 19:15:40,0001,1
0620,2010/10/20 19:35:40,0002,1
0620,2010/10/20 19:35:40,0003,1
0620,2010/10/20 19:35:40,0004,1
0620,2010/10/21 07:13:30,0004,0
0620,2010/10/21 07:13:30,0004,0

How can I script this in python? Any idea of where to begin?

Comment: Have you heard of Google?

Comment: @Nick Castillo: pip install pandas is where you begin